# Passing python variable to linux shell

Tags: python, shell, heredoc

I am running a python snippet inside a heredoc in bash script. I want to pass a string from a python variable to the shell. Perhaps set a shell variable. How can I do this ??

Comment: I could write the variable to a temp file but I want to know if there is any way to send the data back to the shell parent without involving filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

```
variable=$(python - <<EOS
...
EOS
)
```

Whatever the python script writes to stdout will be stored in the variable.

Comment: But This will dump everything the snippet writes, What do I do if I want to selectively send something ?

Comment: Other than writing to a file, I don't think there's a way. A process can't modify variables in another process directly. Either you use files or a pipe.

Comment: I guess using posix IPC would be a way, but that would make the code too complicated. I just want something fast and easy.

Comment: I've decided to implement the whole script functionality in python itself, with a minimal wrapper bash script. Anyway, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.